# How should you handle answers for the wrong game?

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing [this short answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/240569/37419) to a question about Minecraft Story Mode.  The question is about regenerating hearts, and the answerer discusses the hunger mechanics.  However, I believe answerer thinks the question is about Minecraft.  I haven't played Minecraft Story Mode, so I have no idea about the validity of the answer.  I fixed the grammar as part of the review and moved on.

However, I'm wondering if this should be flagged as not an answer.  Looking at this meta answer for [Flagging “answers” that answer a completely different question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4267/37419), I would think that it should be flagged since it doesn't actually answer the question.  However, looking at this answer on the Stack Overflow Meta: [When to flag an answer as “it is not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/691711), I would think that it should be left alone, but **downvoted** since it could be a related answer.

Comment: As a user of Stack Overflow myself, I think their policy around NAA flags is moronic. If you look hard enough *almost anything* can be interpreted as an answer to *something*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already answered your own question:

> Looking at this meta answer for [Flagging “answers” that answer a completely different question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4265/106901), I would think that it should be flagged since it doesn't actually answer the question.

The fact that SO meta says something else doesn't mean anything if we already have answered it on our meta.

The sites are all related but are separate. Different rules and guidelines exist for every site, that while are generally the same or similar, can also sometimes be quite different and even conflicting.